# How to store numbers from an array into a list without also adding strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have .tsv data that is very simple. The first two rows indicate the measurement and units, and the rest of the rows is just straight data:

```
Energy  IncidentFlux
eV  ?
4.0 2.349749705280954e-09
3.99    3.4927474683858684e-09
3.98    5.1237361678671736e-09
3.97    3.737724206016752e-09
3.96    3.556492149406742e-09 
...     ...

data_tsv = []
for l in f:
        #print(l.strip().split())
        data_tsv.append(l.strip().split())
data_tsv = np.array(data_tsv)

energy_eV_tsv = []
eqe_tsv = []
```

I am trying to make a loop that runs through the file, extracting only the numbers so that I may append this to new arrays for separate calculations, but I don't know how to formulate a loop that discriminates numbers from strings.

I've tried if to see if the error converting a string into a float would be a good way to skip the loop, but float is incompatible with arrays...

I've also tried to use a NaN thing I found online, but it said I'm not using that tool correctly.

```
for i in range(len(data_tsv)):
    if np.isnan(data_tsv[i]) == False:
        continue
    a = data_tsv[i]
    energy_eV_tsv.append(a[0])
    eqe_tsv.append(a[1])
```

The goal is to end up with the lists:

```
energy_eV_tsv
eqe_tsv
```

filled with their respective data: energy_eV is first column of data_tsv and eqe is second column of data_tsv WITHOUT any strings in the new lists/arrays.

I do not want to do a loop that has a preset range

```
for i in range(2,len(data_tsv):
...
```

because sometimes the data doesn't have titles, and will erase two lines of data

Answer (score 0):

We can use a try except to convert the string to floats. If it succesfully converts then we can append them to array, otherwise proceed to next line. 
This will check for all the rows, so the initial two lines wont be skipped

```
    energy_eV_tsv = []
    eqe_tsv = []

    with open("data.tsv", "r") as tsvdata:
        line = tsvdata.readline()
        while line != "": # Check if we have reached end of file.
            col1 = line.split()[0]
            col2 = line.split()[1]

            try:
                col1Val = float(col1)
                col2Val = float(col2)
                # Only if both conditions ran without an error
                # will we add the data to our array
                energy_eV_tsv.append(col1Val)
                eqe_tsv.append(col2Val)
            except ValueError:
                print("Detected Strings")

            line = tsvdata.readline()


    print(energy_eV_tsv)
    print(eqe_tsv)
```